# Can't log in to GNOME after upgrade (raring -> saucy)

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, xorg, 13.10

I've just upgraded my `ubuntu` (`raring` to `saucy`) and I now can't log in to `GNOME`. As opposed to virtual consoles (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, for example). I set it up to log in automatically. But it asks for password now. I type in the password, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the screen blinks and here I am again at the login screen. Then I looked into [/var/log/Xorg.0.log](http://sprunge.us/JUKZ):

```
[    33.956] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[    33.956] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    33.956] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    33.956] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    33.956]    compiled for 1.14.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    33.956]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 7.0
[    33.956] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    33.956] Loading extension GLX
[    33.956] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 0
[    33.956] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 1
[    33.956] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 2
[    33.956] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 3
[    33.956] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[    33.956] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 5
[    33.956] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 6
[    33.956] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    33.956] (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
[    33.957] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fglrx
[    33.957] (II) UnloadModule: "fglrx"
[    33.957] (II) Unloading fglrx
[    33.957] (EE) Failed to load module "fglrx" (module does not exist, 0)
[    33.957] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[    33.957] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module ati
[    33.957] (II) UnloadModule: "ati"
[    33.957] (II) Unloading ati
[    33.957] (EE) Failed to load module "ati" (module does not exist, 0)
[    33.957] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    33.957] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    33.957] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    33.957]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 2.3.2
[    33.957]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    33.957]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    33.957] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    33.957] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    33.957] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    33.957]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 0.8.0
[    33.957]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    33.957]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    33.957] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    33.957] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    33.958] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    33.958]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 0.4.3
[    33.958]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    33.958]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    33.958] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 0
[    33.958] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 1
[    33.958] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 2
[    33.958] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 3
[    33.958] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[    33.958] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 5
[    33.958] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 6
[    33.958] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    33.958] (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
[    33.958] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fglrx
[    33.958] (II) UnloadModule: "fglrx"
[    33.958] (II) Unloading fglrx
[    33.958] (EE) Failed to load module "fglrx" (module does not exist, 0)
[    33.958] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[    33.958] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module ati
[    33.958] (II) UnloadModule: "ati"
[    33.958] (II) Unloading ati
[    33.958] (EE) Failed to load module "ati" (module does not exist, 0)
[    33.958] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    33.958] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    33.958] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    33.958]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 2.3.2
[    33.958]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    33.958]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    33.958] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    33.958] (II) Unloading vesa
[    33.958] (II) Failed to load module "vesa" (already loaded, 0)
[    33.958] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    33.959] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    33.959] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    33.959]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 0.8.0
[    33.959]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    33.959]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    33.959] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    33.959] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    33.959] (II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, 0)
[    33.959] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    33.959] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    33.959] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    33.959]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 0.4.3
[    33.959]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    33.959]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    33.959] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    33.959] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    33.959] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 0)
[    33.959] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    33.959] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    33.959] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    33.959] (++) using VT number 7
```

If I install `fglrx`, it [reads](http://sprunge.us/JcYU):

```
[    37.152] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[    37.152] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    37.152] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    37.152] (II) Module glx: vendor="Advanced Micro Devices, Inc."
[    37.152]    compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 1.0.0
[    37.152] Loading extension GLX
[    37.153] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 0
[    37.153] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 1
[    37.153] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[    37.153] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 3
[    37.153] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
[    37.153] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    37.153] (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
[    37.153] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
[    37.168] (II) Module fglrx: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
[    37.168]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 13.10.10
[    37.168]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    37.168] (II) Loading sub module "fglrxdrm"
[    37.168] (II) LoadModule: "fglrxdrm"
[    37.168] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/modules/linux/libfglrxdrm.so
[    37.169] (II) Module fglrxdrm: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
[    37.169]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 13.10.10
[    37.169] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[    37.169] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module ati
[    37.169] (II) UnloadModule: "ati"
[    37.169] (II) Unloading ati
[    37.169] (EE) Failed to load module "ati" (module does not exist, 0)
[    37.169] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    37.169] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    37.169] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    37.169]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 2.3.2
[    37.169]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    37.169]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    37.169] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    37.170] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    37.170] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    37.170]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 0.8.0
[    37.170]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    37.170]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    37.170] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    37.170] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    37.170] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    37.170]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 0.4.3
[    37.170]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    37.170]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    37.170] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 0
[    37.170] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 1
[    37.170] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[    37.170] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 3
[    37.170] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
[    37.170] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    37.170] (II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
[    37.170] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
[    37.170] (II) Module fglrx: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
[    37.170]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 13.10.10
[    37.170]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    37.170] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[    37.170] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module ati
[    37.170] (II) UnloadModule: "ati"
[    37.171] (II) Unloading ati
[    37.171] (EE) Failed to load module "ati" (module does not exist, 0)
[    37.171] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    37.171] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    37.171] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    37.171]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 2.3.2
[    37.171]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    37.171]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    37.171] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    37.171] (II) Unloading vesa
[    37.171] (II) Failed to load module "vesa" (already loaded, 0)
[    37.171] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    37.171] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    37.171] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    37.171]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 0.8.0
[    37.171]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    37.171]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    37.171] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    37.171] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    37.171] (II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, 0)
[    37.171] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    37.171] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    37.171] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    37.171]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 0.4.3
[    37.171]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    37.171]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    37.171] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    37.171] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    37.171] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 0)
[    37.171] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Version Identifier:13.10.10
[    37.171] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Release Identifier: UNSUPPORTED-13.101                   
[    37.171] (II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Build Date: May 23 2013 15:49:35
[    37.171] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    37.171] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    37.171] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    37.171] (++) using VT number 7
```

I did more installing/removing packages than that. There were a moment when it said:

```
(EE) Failed to load /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so: /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so: undefined symbol: _glapi_tls_Context
```

Also there is `init: not found` in `~/.xsession-errors`:

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: 5: exec: init: not found
```

Actually, I'm out of ideas. What about you? :)

**UPD** I've got the same problem on another machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone mangled with PATH.

Edit your `.profile` and add to the end:

```
PATH="/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH"
```

Then restart lightdm:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

It's maybe the bug stated by darkhole

Comment: You saved my day, the problem was with the `PATH`. [This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1184878) seems more relevant. I'd add though that the PATH to be expected is in `/etc/environment`.

Comment: Fantastic, this saved my ass! I had played with /etc/environment during the update, as I had added stuff there previously and it was causing other problems. I had disabled the whole `PATH=` line and the `sbin` stuff were gone. Not sure if the OP had done exactly the same.

Comment: I would upvote this 10,000 times if I could.  This fixed the problems I have been having for days now!

Answer (score 0):

Please post all your .xsession-errors file. Maybe this is a bug mentioned here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1228079

Are you using pbis-open to join the PC to a Domain?

Comment: [Here](http://sprunge.us/dJAT) it is. There are two files (+ old one) and they are identical. However, as far as I can tell when I looked into it, it was [like this](http://sprunge.us/DAcD).

Comment: Oh, I've got no domain controller on my network.

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed this for me by deleting .dmrc.

Actually I deleted a lot of dot files from my home directory on the assumption that there was a misconfiguration. .dmrc was one of the last things I deleted.