# login loop after upgrading to 14.04 from Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 14.04

After upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 I get a login loop.

However, I'm able to login using terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>), and also checked the `~/.xsession-errors` file.

It showed `/usr/sbin/lightdm-session : exec 5: init: permission denied`. I also tried removing the `~/.XAuthority` file but it didn't work.

Permissions of Xauthority files are user, so no problem there. What can I do?

**xsession.errors file:**

```
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: 5: exec: init: Permission denied
```

**lightdm x-0-greeter.log:**

```
Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
[+0.00s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:496: Starting unity-greeter 14.04.10 UID=104 LANG=en_IN
[+0.00s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:499: Setting cursor
[+0.00s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:513: Loading command line options
[+0.00s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:541: Setting GTK+ settings
Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'

** (at-spi2-registryd:3010): WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

** (at-spi2-registryd:3010): WARNING **: Unable to register client with session manager
[+0.07s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:564: Creating Unity Greeter
[+0.07s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:57: Creating background surface
[+0.07s] DEBUG: Connecting to display manager...
[+0.07s] DEBUG: Wrote 18 bytes to daemon
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Read 8 bytes from daemon
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Read 150 bytes from daemon
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Connected version=1.10.1 default-session=ubuntu show-manual-login=false hide-users=false has-guest-account=true show-remote-login=true
[+0.11s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:335: LANG=en_IN LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
[+0.12s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:367: LANG=en_IN LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
[+0.12s] DEBUG: Loading users from org.freedesktop.Accounts
[+0.12s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 added
[+0.14s] DEBUG: user-list.vala:1030: Adding/updating user ashish (Ashish Jain)
[+0.14s] DEBUG: Loading sessions from org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.15s] DEBUG: user-list.vala:1012: Adding guest account entry
[+0.27s] DEBUG: Loaded session /usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop (Ubuntu, This session logs you into Ubuntu)
[+0.27s] DEBUG: Ignoring session /usr/share/xsessions/gnome.desktop
[+0.27s] DEBUG: Starting authentication for user ashish...
[+0.27s] DEBUG: Wrote 22 bytes to daemon
[+0.27s] DEBUG: main-window.vala:185: Screen is 1366x768 pixels
[+0.27s] DEBUG: main-window.vala:193: Monitor 0 is 1366x768 pixels at 0,0
[+0.27s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:567: Showing greeter
[+0.27s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:252: Showing main window
[+0.28s] DEBUG: background.vala:483: Regenerating backgrounds
[+0.28s] DEBUG: background.vala:68: Making background /usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png at 1366x768
[+0.29s] WARNING: unity-greeter.vala:587: Error starting Upstart for indicators: Failed to execute child process "init" (Permission denied)
[+0.30s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:610: Starting main loop
[+0.30s] DEBUG: Read 8 bytes from daemon
[+0.30s] DEBUG: Read 36 bytes from daemon
[+0.30s] DEBUG: Prompt user with 1 message(s)
[+0.31s] DEBUG: background.vala:68: Making background /home/ashish/Pictures/red_fox_sleeping-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg at 1366x768
[+0.31s] DEBUG: background.vala:159: Error loading background: Failed to open file '/home/ashish/Pictures/red_fox_sleeping-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg': Permission denied
[+0.36s] DEBUG: settings-daemon.vala:75: Acquired org.gnome.SessionManager
[+0.36s] DEBUG: settings-daemon.vala:102: Acquired org.gnome.ScreenSaver
[+0.36s] DEBUG: settings-daemon.vala:159: All bus names acquired, starting unity-settings-daemon
[+0.38s] DEBUG: unity-greeter.vala:235: starting system-ready sound
[+0.42s] DEBUG: background.vala:121: Render of background /home/ashish/Pictures/red_fox_sleeping-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg complete
[+0.42s] DEBUG: background.vala:138: images[0] was null for /home/ashish/Pictures/red_fox_sleeping-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg
[+0.44s] DEBUG: main-window.vala:185: Screen is 1366x768 pixels
[+0.44s] DEBUG: main-window.vala:193: Monitor 0 is 1366x768 pixels at 0,0

** (unity-settings-daemon:3047): WARNING **: Unable to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method 'RegisterClient'
[+0.56s] DEBUG: menubar.vala:537: Adding indicator object 0x9e16244 at position 0
[+0.57s] DEBUG: background.vala:121: Render of background /usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png complete

** (nm-applet:3041): CRITICAL **: nm_secret_agent_register: assertion 'priv->registered == FALSE' failed
nm-applet-Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
[+303.61s] DEBUG: settings-daemon.vala:209: Screensaver activated
[+625.69s] DEBUG: settings-daemon.vala:211: Screensaver disabled
[+630.60s] DEBUG: Starting authentication for guest account...
[+630.60s] DEBUG: Wrote 12 bytes to daemon
[+630.60s] DEBUG: Read 8 bytes from daemon
[+630.60s] DEBUG: Read 12 bytes from daemon
[+630.60s] DEBUG: Authentication complete for user  with return code 0
[+631.58s] DEBUG: Starting authentication for user ashish...
[+631.58s] DEBUG: Wrote 22 bytes to daemon
[+631.59s] DEBUG: Read 8 bytes from daemon
[+631.59s] DEBUG: Read 36 bytes from daemon
[+631.59s] DEBUG: Prompt user with 1 message(s)
[+934.66s] DEBUG: settings-daemon.vala:209: Screensaver activated
```

Comment: its login loop you should install in loop if problem doesnt go away

Comment: What.... I don't understand what are you saying, can you elaborate, please?

Comment: Just got the same issue. I had mangled with my $PATH... see http://askubuntu.com/questions/360725/cant-log-in-to-gnome-after-upgrade-raring-saucy